# Why can't I import EnvDTE though I referenced xtensibility.dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Prog deos'nt compile with

using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine;

I haved added extensibility.dll to references. What's more missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Visual Studio Add-in** project using the New Project Wizard (search for **add-in** with "Search Installed Templates") and then look at what references are provided in the Add-in project template.